# How do I give a concrete value to a Haskell instance?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I'm a bit confused by this infamous "rigid type variable" error.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```hs
class Ord v => Vector v where
  distance :: v -> v -> Double

-- with FlexibleInstances
instance Vector (Double, Double) where
  distance (a,b) (c,d) = -- function definition omitted

data KMeansState v = KMeansState { centroids :: [v] }

test :: [(Double,Double)]
test = [(0,0),(1,1)] :: [(Double,Double)]

initializeState :: Vector v => Int -> KMeansState v
initializeState n = KMeansState test
```

The specific complaint that the compiler is giving me:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘v’ with ‘(Double, Double)’
      ‘v’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          initializeState :: forall v.
                             Vector v =>
                             Int -> Double -> KMeansState v
        at Chapter06.hs:32:1-61
      Expected type: KMeansState v
        Actual type: KMeansState (Double, Double)
```

My understanding is that the compiler is saying my `initializeState` function needs to be able to return (or whatever the right word is in Haskell) a `KMeansState` whose type parameter is *any* type that's an instance of `Vector`, while the actual implementation of my function will only return *one* type, namely a `KMeansState (Double, Double)`.

What I'm not clear on is how to get a "concrete" value out of this `initializeState` function. At some point in the program, I need to give the `KMeansState` constructor an actual value which will have an actual type, and it seems like the compiler is saying that I can't do that.

I'm further confused by why the code compiles if I hard code the value of the `test` function into `initializeState`. That is, this successfully type-checks, even though the value being passed to the `KMeansState` function should be functionally the same.

```hs
class Ord v => Vector v where
  distance :: v -> v -> Double

-- with FlexibleInstances
instance Vector (Double, Double) where
  distance (a,b) (c,d) = -- function definition omitted

data KMeansState v = KMeansState { centroids :: [v] }

-- test :: [(Double,Double)]
-- test = [(0,0),(1,1)] :: [(Double,Double)]

initializeState :: Vector v => Int -> KMeansState v
initializeState n = KMeansState [(0,0),(1,1)]::[(Double,Double)]
```

Can someone please clarify what's going on here and how I get this to compile? Thanks!

Comment: The type constraint `Vector v =>` means that you promise that this will work for *every* `v` that is an instance of `Vector`. So the "user" can decide what the value for `v` is, but here you fill this in yourself, you specify that it is a `v ~ (Double, Double)`. In that case the signature is just `initalizeState :: Int -> KMeansState (Double, Double)`.

Comment: Your code that supposedly “successfully type-checks” doesn't even parse properly (it parses as `(KMeansState [(0,0),(1,1)]) :: [(Double,Double)]`, which is certainly nonsense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common, fundamental misunderstanding about what Haskell typeclasses are / how they work. Concretely, a Haskell class is *not* like a class in OO languages. It is in some ways like an interface / abstract class, but that too not really.

In particular, you can't have “concrete values of a class”. Classes don't have values, they have *instances* – but those are types, not values. (These types then may or may not have values – in fact, strictly speaking they don't need to be types at all, just type-level entities.)

What you *intend* to say with your signature to the `initializeState` function is “the result is a value of type `KMeansState v`, where `v` is some type that is an instance of the `Vector` class but I don't want to tell you which”. What it actually says is, “for any type `v` that you pick, provided it is an instance of the `Vector` class, `initializeState` is a function that yields a `KMeansState v` value”. Because of the “for any”, aka “forall” or ∀, we call this a *universally quantified type*.

The intended type meanwhile is *existentially* quantified. It's a bit weird why this would be called so; it's a bit more understandable if I phrase it as “the result is a value `r` for which there exists a type `v` that has a `Vector` instance, such that `r` has the type `KMeansState v`”.

While Haskell has always had universally quantified types, it doesn't really have existential ones. What you can do is wrap an existential in a custom type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data SomeVectorMeanState where
  SomeVectorMeanState :: Vector v => KMeansState v -> SomeVectorMeanState

initializeState :: Int -> SomeVectorMeanState
initializeState n = SomeVectorMeanState $ KMeansState test
```

But this doesn't really accomplish anything useful. In fact, you won't be able to use the vector values in any way whatsoever, because the concrete type isn't known. See https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Instead, as Willem Van Onsem commented, you should probably just use

```
initializeState :: Int -> KMeansState (Double,Double)
```

or, if you don't want to make it so obvious that the vector type is `(Double,Double)`, you can wrap it in a `type` or `newtype`.